# Is it at all idiomatic to say "between doing something and doing something else, I've realized that..."?

Tags: idioms

I'm writing a personal statement and I want to explain that while on a language learning journey and, later on, on a language teaching career, I realized what languages actually represent in the world. While doing it, I had a feeling that if I wrote something like

> between learning and teaching, I've realized that...

it would be fine, but I'd like someone to back this up first.

Comment: Between commenting and doing nothing else, I feel I've answered this question.

Comment: You mean the sense [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between) gives for **between**: << 6: taking together the combined effect of
_between work and family life, they have no time for hobbies_ >>, I suppose? (It _could_ be read as << between the learning and the teaching stages of my life, I've realized that ...). There's usually a negative (in the human attitude sense) statement after a 'between' (sense 6) phrase. I'd say the same about 'what with', though to a lesser degree. I'm toying with 'A realisation informed by both my learning and my teaching of the language has ...'.

Comment: It is not idiomatic to write "sth".

Comment: @tchrist I have no clue what "sth" means, and I've lived in the U.S. all my life.  May not be idiomatic, but it is not ubiquitous.

Comment: @Felipe A question posted to stackexchange is not a text. If you mean to represent saying the word "*something*", type that word, rather than using a textspeak abbreviation; it will be better understood (and be easier for people searching later). Also if the two somethings are distinct, it would be usual to refer to the the second by "*another thing*" or "*something else*".

Comment: @Glen_b: using "sth" as a placeholder for a noun in a description of usage is an academic convention, not "textspeak". It's standard in reference works.

Comment: I am sorry if my abbreviation misled anybody or might have caused difficulty for people looking for the same answer as me. However, I wrote it like that because I see it all the time in many online dictionaries, such as Cambridge's: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/break-sth-in

Answer (score 12):

This is a correct locution for expressing what you have in mind, as shows the folowing [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/between_1?q=between) definition.

> **​between doing something** -  used to show that several activities are involved
> *Between working full-time and taking care of the kids, he didn't have much time for hobbies.*

There is, however, another one, which is "**what with**" (it's the object of **user 121863**'s answwer). I couldn't assert which of the two locutions is more common or preferred but it seems to me that  "*what with*" would be  somewhat more expressive, maybe because of its carrying no ambiguity.

Comment: I suspect that ***what with*** may be more of a BrE usage than AmE, but I can't easily show that. I also suspect that ***and all*** is relatively common for the second "distracting activity", but that one only really works in ***I've been busy, what with work and all*** (I'm not so keen on ***...between work and all*** there).

Comment: As an American, "what with" is fine but means a complaint is coming. "Between" is more neutral.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not at all. We use what with all the time in AmE. ///However, locution in French and English are usually false friends. In English, we say phrase.

Comment: "This is a correct locution for expressing what you have in mind, as shows the folowing [typo]  OALD definition". Correction: This is  correct **phrasing** for expressing what you have in mind, as the following OALD definition **shows**. Grammar.

Comment: @Lambie  On this page, https://www.google.com/search?q=%22locution%20is%20not%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en, check those: "this locution is not entirely clear, the locution is not allowed, the locution is not valid, odd locution is not necessarily senseless". In particular, "a valid locution" is seen as direct consequence. Why then decide that "correct locution" is not a possibility? I agree that "correct phrasing" would be more usual, but that is no reason to make it the exclusive term to refer to a string of words. (1/2)

Comment: @Lambie  "Correct expression" is found often enough: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+correct+expression&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20correct%20expression%3B%2Cc0. However, you shouldn't be able to use a synonym for "expression"? Nonsense! (2/2)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the idiomatic expression [what with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/what-with):

> What with learning  and teaching, I have realized ..

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I like much better [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/what#what_idmg_14)' s definition: "used to list the various reasons for something - 
What with the cold weather and my bad leg, I haven't been out for weeks.".

Answer (score 5):

I am going to disagree with the highly upvoted answer by @LPH

*Between* refers to a place that is neither one thing nor another.

> Between working full-time and taking care of the kids, he didn't have
> much time for hobbies.

This means that there was no time or space between working and caretaking to have a hobby.

> between learning and teaching, I've realized that...

This could mean that you took a break between learning and teaching and it was during that gap that you realized something.

At best it is ambiguous.

---

**Suggestions**

*Through learning and teaching, I've realized that...*

*Having experienced both learning and teaching, I've realized that...*

*Having been both learner and teacher, I've realized that...*

Comment: In the expression discussed 'between' indicates a connection or relationship involving two or more things.  This is the fourth definition provided by Google/OL, one of the more idiomatic ones.  OP specifically asked whether the phrase was idiomatic.  It is.

Comment: Phrases do not always mean the same thing as the words that make them up. The word-wise literal interpretation proposed here imposes constraints on the OP's "between gerund and gerund" phrase that don't align with the OALD definition referenced above, or my (Am. English) experience of the phrase in the wild.

OP's proposed usage feels absolutely natural to my Am. English ear. It may be slightly less formal than the good suggestions made in this answer, but not inappropriate for a personal statement.

Comment: @Chris Keefe - Maybe this is an AmE, BrE difference.